# DataTables jQuery plugin setting recordsTotal after initial load

Tags: jquery, performance, datatables

I've scoured the internet and SO for this but can't seem to find an answer...

I have a relatively intricate query that returns 50 records from a large database.  This query runs as a cursor so it is fast and is able to assemble the json and return to datatables in ~20ms.

However, getting the overall count of records for this query is slower (500ms).

I would like to be able to do a parallel ajax call and set the count (recordsCount) on my data table after it has already rendered so I can see data on the screen faster.  Is this possible?

As a workaround I am considering creating a cache of counts for my queries,  but this seems non-ideal if I could easily hit some client side code when I'm able to get the count.

Here is my datatables code for reference:

```
var table = $('#myTable').DataTable({
    "dom": '<"top"iflp<"clear">>rt<"bottom"iflp<"clear">>',
    "processing": true,
    "serverSide": true,
    "searching": false,
    "ordering": false,
    "bSort": false,
    "scrollX": false,
    "fixedHeader": true,
    "deferRender": true,
    "iDisplayStart": (startPage * pageLength),
    "ajax": {
      "url": url,
      "type": "POST",
      "data": function (d) {

      }
    },
    "pagingType": "full_numbers",
    "columnDefs": columnDefs,
    "responsive": false,
    "columns": columnDataStructure,
    "order": [[0, "desc"]],
    "lengthMenu": [10,25,50,100],
    "initComplete": function(settings, json){

    }
  })
```

Answer (score 1):

It's an interesting question.

I can offer you a hacky way to do it. It should work for DataTables 1.10.x.

Attach the following event handler that will be called when DataTables makes Ajax request to your server-side script.

Call another server-side method (`/echo/json/` in my example) and retrieve total number of records.

Then update DataTables using some internal undocumented function.

```
$('#example').on('xhr.dt', function ( e, settings, json, xhr ) {
   $.ajax({
      url: '/echo/json/',
      method: 'POST',
      data: { json: JSON.stringify({ recordsTotal: 999 }) },
      type: 'json'
   })
   .done(function(json){
      settings._iRecordsDisplay = json.recordsTotal;
      settings._iRecordsTotal = json.recordsTotal;     
      $.fn.dataTable.ext.internal._fnCallbackFire( settings, 'aoDrawCallback', 'draw', [settings] );
   });
});
```

See [this example](https://jsfiddle.net/gsduwg8r/) for code and demonstration.

Comment: @Rao, don't forget to return some dummy numbers for `recordsTotal` and `recordsFiltered` in your original response.